# Get states of tasks ran by bluebird.all().spread()

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have two tasks ran by Bluebird:

```
// Require bluebird...
var Promise = require("bluebird");

// Run two tasks together
Promise
  .all([Git.getRemotes(), GitFtp.getFtpRemotes()])
  .spread(function (remotes, ftpRemotes) {
    // Something cool
  });
```

With **q.js** I had as response:

```
remotes.value (the response of my task)
remotes.state ("fullfilled" or "rejected" depending if the task thrown an error or not)
ftpRemotes.value
ftpRemotes.state
```

So inside the `spread()` part I was able to check the state of each task.
[This is the code I was using before Bluebird](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/pull/285/files#diff-0224e385b6639a5ed21be8015fcaebcfR207)

With bluebird I get just:

```
remotes
ftpRemotes
```

Containing just the array generated by my tasks.

**I think I need `Promise.allSettled` but I can't find it in the documentation.**
How can I get the state of each task?

Comment: If you want things to maybe fail you can use `Promise.settle` but I doubt that's what you actually need here.

Comment: The two functions just returns one array for each one, I don't think it's relevant. By the way the source code is in this PR https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/pull/288

Comment: What do you mean with "I had as response" ? Is that some log ? Where ?

Comment: **q** retturns in the "value" key a "fullfilled" string if the specific task went good, and a "rejected" if something went wrong.

Comment: @FezVrasta: You didn't use `Q.all`, but `Q.allSettled`, did you?

Comment: right, I've replaced it with "all" instead of "settle"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to handle the case they're good/bad together:

```
//Require bluebird...
var Promise = require("bluebird");

// Run two tasks together
Promise
  .all([Git.getRemotes(), GitFtp.getFtpRemotes()])
  .spread(function (remotes, ftpRemotes) {
    // Something cool
  }).catch(function(err){
    // handle errors on both
  });
```

If you want to wait for both to either resolve or reject use `Promise.settle`:

```
Promise
  .settle([Git.getRemotes(), GitFtp.getFtpRemotes()])
  .spread(function(remotesStatus,ftpRemoteStatus){
        // the two are PromiseInspection objects and have:
        // isFullfilled, isRejected, value() etc.
  });
```