# angular $q and google.maps.api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, asynchronous, promise

I'm struggleling since hours trying to understand how is working $q.
I'm trying to make it works with a function from the google.maps api but I'm definitely not able to answer it by myself or maybe I totally don't understand $q.
I hope you'll be able to help me or at least give me some explanation.

Here is a very simple example of what I would like to do :

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
let promise1 = geocoder.geocode({address: "someAddress"});
let promise2 = geocoder.geocode({address: "someOtherAddress"});
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(data => { 
    console.log(data) 
});

//The ouput I get is : [undefined, undefined] but it's definitely not what I expect :P
```

Where am I wrong ? Here is the original async method from google api which works fine.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({address: "someAddress"}, function(response, status){
    if(status === 'ok')
        //Do what I need with the response
    else
        //Do something else
});
```

The thing is I want to do do something with multiple requests, not only one. 
So I need to store all the responses (and wait for them to be stored as it's an async function) before doing something. 
That's why I try to use $q to reach my goal.

PS: Maybe it's a double thread because I saw a lot of discussion about $q but even after hours of researches I can't find an issue... So please don't tell me to google it.

Thanks by advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.geocode` doesn't return a Promise, it uses a callback (as you know) and returns `undefined` as you've found out

You can make a "promisified" geocode function, along the lines of

```
const geocodePromise = (geocoder, params) => new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
    geocoder.geocode(params, function(response, status) {
        if (status == 'ok') resolve(response);
        else reject(status);
    });
});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
let promise1 = geocodePromise(geocoder, {address: "someAddress"});
let promise2 = geocodePromise(geocoder, {address: "someOtherAddress"});
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(data => { 
    console.log(data) 
});
```

or

```
google.maps.Geocoder.geocodeP = function geocodeP(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
        this.geocode(params, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'ok') resolve(response);
            else reject(status);
        });
    });
};
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
let promise1 = geocoder.geocodeP({address: "someAddress"});
let promise2 = geocoder.geocodeP({address: "someOtherAddress"});
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(data => { 
    console.log(data) 
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lots !!! I tried your first proposition and it works perfectely. In fact I tought $q was waiting for the geocode functions and callbacks to finish, I didnt understand I had to 'transform' them in promises first. Now its more clear to me :)

Answer (score 0):

what node module you're using? google-maps-api?

```
geocoder.geocode({address: "someAddress"});
```

returns a promise or
try do this

```
geocoder.geocode({address: "someAddress"}).then(data => console.log(data));
```

if it returns `undefined` then the one causing the problem is the API it self.

if data is not `undefined` then the `geocoder.geocode()` part is is not causing the problem

you can try this library [Get states of tasks ran by bluebird.all().spread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658992/get-states-of-tasks-ran-by-bluebird-all-spread)

for the "double thread" you mention, JavaScript don't support multi thread. you can refer to this link [Why doesn't JavaScript support multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading)

Comment: In fact I didnt really understand how promises worked and the 'geocode' function had to be 'promisified' like Jaromanda said. Thanks for your help though :)